# THREE.OBJLoader - Scale mesh and BufferGeometry vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry, objloader

I'm using [THREE.OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader) to load a 3D model into my scene. It works fine.

However, after adding it to the scene, I need to scale it by 10, then retrieve its vertices position.

I know that `THREE.OBJLoader` gives me a `BufferGeometry`, and I know how to access its vertices using `position` attribute.

My problem is: the `Float32Array` storing these vertices doesn't seem to be updated after scaling my mesh, whether I do it before or after adding it to the scene.

I use this snippet to scale the mesh just after I got it from the loader:

```
myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(loadedMesh.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000}));
myMesh.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
```

Then I get the vertices using:

```
var myMeshVertices = myMesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
```

Doing that, my mesh is added to the scene with the proper (scaled) dimensions, but its `BufferGeometry` doesn't want to update the vertices values.

I did a lot of tests involving `myMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;` or `myMesh.updateMatrix();`, and I've seen a lot of SO questions around this subject ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303239/three-js-how-to-update-buffergeometry-vertices) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430260/threejs-buffergeometry-position-attribute-not-updating-when-translation-applied)), but I couldn't find a solution...

Could you tell me if I misunderstand something here? (keeping in mind that I just began with Three.js and WebGL, so I most certainly lack knowledge about this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
myMesh.geometry.scale( 10, 10, 10 );
```

Scaling an instance of `Object3D` and its subclasses means you apply a scale to its internal `matrix` and consequently its `worldMatrix`. This matrix is later used in the vertex shader in order to transform your vertices. If you need the transformation already on CPU side, use the respective transform methods of `BufferGeometry`.

Comment: WOW! I didn't even imagine it could be so simple... Thank you for the answer (that's not the first time you help me understand something about GLSL ;))